# Unexpected XML element "_x0078_ml" in babelfish

Tags: sql-server, xml, babelfish

```
create table #emp
(
id int,
name varchar(10)
);
insert into #emp values(1,'A'),(2,'B');

create table #prd
(
prid int,
price int
);
insert into #prd values(1,299),(2,295);
```

Expected Output: I want to display result as shown below.

```
<SampleData>
    <EmpData id="1" name="A" />
    <EmpData id="2" name="B" />
    <PrdData prid="1" price="299" />
    <PrdData prid="2" price="295" />
</SampleData>
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT 
    (
        SELECT id,
               name 
        FROM #emp
        FOR XML RAW('EmpData'),TYPE 
    ),
    (
        SELECT prid,
               price
        FROM #prd
        FOR XML RAW('PrdData'),TYPE
    )
    FOR XML PATH('SampleData'),TYPE
);
```

Output:

```
<SampleData>
  <_x0078_ml>
    <EmpData id="1" name="A" />
    <EmpData id="2" name="B" />
  </_x0078_ml>
  <_x0078_ml>
    <PrdData prid="1" price="299" />
    <PrdData prid="2" price="295" />
  </_x0078_ml>
</SampleData>
```

**Note**: The query works fine in SQL Server but not getting extra XML element **_x0078_ml** in Babelfish. I need this query to be compatible for both (SQL Server and Babelfish).

Comment: Just adding if JSON is an option, you would not see this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FOR XML PATH` instead, and specify the attribute names explicitly.

```sql
SELECT 
(
    SELECT 
    (
        SELECT id AS [@id],
               name AS [@name]
        FROM #emp
        FOR XML PATH('EmpData'),TYPE 
    ),
    (
        SELECT prid AS [@prid],
               price AS [@price]
        FROM #prd
        FOR XML PATH('PrdData'),TYPE
    )
    FOR XML PATH('SampleData'),TYPE
);
```

Alternatively use `FOR XML AUTO`, although this is more difficult to control the exact shape of the XML.

```sql
SELECT 
(
    SELECT 
    (
        SELECT id,
               name 
        FROM #emp AS EmpData
        FOR XML AUTO,TYPE 
    ),
    (
        SELECT prid,
               price
        FROM #prd AS PrdData
        FOR XML AUTO,TYPE
    )
    FOR XML PATH('SampleData'),TYPE
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/f9TjeO_F)

Comment: 'FOR XML AUTO mode' is not currently supported in Babelfish and first query also not work as expected. First query shows `<SampleData>
  <_x0078_ml>
    <EmpData>
      <_x0040_id>1</_x0040_id>
      <_x0040_name>A</_x0040_name>
    </EmpData>......`

Comment: Looks like a bug, that's definitely correct SQL Server syntax, see fiddle

Answer (score 0):

As @Charlieface already said, it looks like a bug in Babelfish.

It seems that it is adding an artificial `<_x0078_ml>` root element in the sub-queries.

Please try a workaround below for that.

Its basic idea to introduce a post-processing step via XQuery to remove not needed sub-queries root element.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @emp table (id int, name varchar(10));
INSERT @emp values(1,'A'),(2,'B');

DECLARE @prd TABLE (prid int, price int);
INSERT @prd values(1,299),(2,295);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT (
SELECT 
(
    SELECT id AS [@id],
        name AS [@name]
    FROM @emp
    FOR XML PATH('EmpData'),TYPE, ROOT('root') 
),
(
    SELECT prid AS [@prid],
        price AS [@price]
    FROM @prd
    FOR XML PATH('PrdData'),TYPE, ROOT('root') 
)
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE, ROOT('SampleData')
).query('<SampleData>
{
    for $x in /SampleData/root/*
    return $x
}
</SampleData>');
```

**Output**

```
<SampleData>
  <EmpData id="1" name="A" />
  <EmpData id="2" name="B" />
  <PrdData prid="1" price="299" />
  <PrdData prid="2" price="295" />
</SampleData>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried aliasing the xml subqueries with node() or * ?

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT id,
           name 
    FROM #emp
    FOR XML RAW('EmpData'),TYPE 
)[node()],
(
    SELECT prid,
           price
    FROM #prd
    FOR XML RAW('PrdData'),TYPE
)[*]
```